Решить задачу коммивояжёра с помощью networkx
Получаю граф места и выбираю в нем ближайшие к координатам узлы:
g_walk = ox.graph_from_place('Россия, Челябинск', network_type='walk')

coords = [(61.31225419798328,55.18981241711393), 
          
          (61.33434716529909,55.18440454683216),

          (61.319002751797505,55.17747320583725)
]

nodes = [ox.nearest_nodes(g_walk, point[0], point[1]) for point in coords]

Что и как нужно использовать из библиотеки networkx для решения TSP для выбранных узлов в nodes?

nx.approximation.traveling_salesman_problem, очевидно.
